# Alternative of XML Starlet

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

Is there any alternative to `XML starlet` for XML processing in `bash`? My typical usage is:

- pretty formatting;
- selecting data by `XPath`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html).

To format xml:

```
$ xmllint --format file.xml
```

To evaluate an XPath:

```
$ xmllint --format --shell file.xml <<< "cat /some/xpath/expression"
```